# Exiting a process after a database call in Node?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm experimenting with calling a database from Node, and am using the following client.execute() sample code

```
socket.on('send', function(data){

    client.execute('SELECT * FROM db.main', [], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            //do something
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                console.log('id=' + result.rows[i].get('topic_id'));
            }

            process.exit(0);

        }
    });
 });
```

As seen above, I'm running this code inside a socket.io listener method. However, the server stops whenever it is executed. On the other hand, when I remove 'process.exit(0)', things seem to run just fine.

So is that line necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The line: `process.exit(0);` will exit your program, i guess it was put there for debugging purpose or smth.

Answer (score 0):

You generally should never need to manually call `process.exit(0)`. If there is nothing left to do, the process will exit naturally.